# I want to run a .net web application on local computer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I wanted to run a .net application on a laptop. I created the application(aspx pages and SQL database) on a computer that has VS 08 installed. Now i wanted to run this application on a laptop that does not have SQL sever 2005 installed.

As far as the aspx pages if i publish them to a zip drive copy it to my laptop and go into IIS and define a new virtual directory to point where my pages are that should work RIGHT??

Now for the database i don't know what i need to do

any ideas???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publish the web app to a folder on the laptop and create an IIS Virtual directory pointing to that folder.

As for the DB, install an express version of SQL Server (http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/) and 
point you web app at them.

Comment: is there a way i can create a back-up of my database? and just import it into the new SQL server?

Comment: Sure. You can export from your existing SQL Server and import the file to the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using SQL Server Compact Edition? This will allow you to move the db around with the application.

Comment: And SQL Server Express is a way to put a free SQL Server on any machine.

Comment: @Jeremy Just a side note, if you are talking about what I think you are, I think when you do this then each windows user gets a seperate clean copy of the database normally, so no data is shared.  Although since this is a web app I wonder if there will be a single shared database simply because it is access by the ASP.NET user account.

Comment: no it will not be a shared database. 

any help documents on how to use the SQL sever CE, or how i can i set-up my database

Answer (score 2):

You need to install sql server on the client(laptop) so you can run the application properly

Answer (score 2):

> As far as the aspx pages if i publish
>   them to a zip drive copy it to my
>   laptop and go into IIS and define a
>   new virtual directory to point where
>   my pages are that should work RIGHT??

Yes this should work.

As for the database, you'll need to install it on the computer you are running IIS on and copy the schema and data over or (I would recommend this way) have your code connect to a server which has the database on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install at a minimum SQL Server 2005 express edition.  You may also need to change the connection settings for your application, which may be in your .config file(depending on how you did your conneciton in your application) and depending on whether the server instance and database name you choose are different from what you used on your development computer.